# Spring MVC DeferredResult streaming (Java 8 Streams or RxJava)

Tags: spring-mvc, stream, rx-java

Can DeferredResult handle streams of data somehow? Looks like when I use the DeferredResult.setResult using a stream, it only returns the first item and ignores the rest of them.

Same behaviour if using an Observable from rxjava.

Thanks.

Comment: nope. As the result of a controller is send as a whole, you can't stream data, unless you want to use SSE or Websocket (in this case, you can look at a ResponseBodyEmitter => http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.0.RC2/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-async-http-streaming )

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense in the terms of DeferredResult, given that it present the whole result at once.